# Cx_Freeze's extra stuff

Tags: python, exe, cx-freeze

Whenever I build an exe with cx_Freeze and Python I get a bunch of extra stuff like the Library.zip and all the .dll files. Is there a way I can make it just one executable file that I can just send over to someone and have them run without having to give them all the extra files also? Python 3.4. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Not really<sup>1</sup>. You're best option for a single-file distribution is probably to create an [installer](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page).

You can however append the library.zip to your executable:

```
 params['options'] = {
     'append_script_to_exe': True,
     'create_shared_zip': False,
      ...
 }
 setup(**params)
```

But this only reduces the number of files by 1.

There are two reasons why you can't do this. The first is that some modules are not "zip safe" (those that contain data files that are read with `open()`). The second, and more important reason, is that Python requires various DLLs in order to run, and Windows's dynamic linker doesn't know how to find and load those DLLs if they're inside a zip file.

See: http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#single-file-executables

---

<sup>1</sup> If you're really ambitious, you could theoretically create an entirely static build of Python (statically link all of the library source code, and the C runtimes, etc.), *and* do the same with any C modules that you might be using. That plus appending the Library.zip file to the exe might give you a single-file distribution.

However, tracking down and building all those dependencies would be a *very large* effort.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, If your on windows this method works.

Run ->> iexpress

Follow the instructions.

This will compile all the files into on exe but first you need to create the exe using cx_freeze then browse to the directory in iexpress and it will do the rest.